# Django Dynamic initial values for current user

Tags: django, file-upload

I want the current user to be able to upload a file in my html page. I try a method but it didn't work. I have an error message :"File.userFile" must be a "Customer" instance

Here's my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class File(models.Model):
    userFile = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    document = models.FileField()
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.document
```

forms.py

```
class FichierUpload(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['userFile']
```

views.py

```
def my_view(request, **kwargs):
    print(f"Great! You're using Python 3.6+. If you fail here, use the right version.")
    message = 'Upload as many files as you want!'
    # Handle file upload
    current_user= request.user.username
    #fileuser = Customer.objects.get(user=current_user)
    form = FichierUpload(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       # if form.is_valid():
        file = form.save(commit=False)
        file.userFile = request.user
        file.save()
         # Redirect to the document list after POST
        return redirect('my-view')
       # else:
        #    message = 'The form is not valid. Fix the following error:'
    else:
        form = FichierUpload()  # An empty, unbound form
    
    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = File.objects.filter(userFile__name=current_user).order_by('-uploaded_at')

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    context = {'documents': documents, 'form': form, 'message': message}
    return render(request, 'myApp/dossierClient.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `file.userFile = request.user` is settings the user instance, not the customer instance.
Try changing it to

`file.userFile = request.user.customer`

In the future you might solve this with a custom user model, combining user & customer properties into one model.